# Unable to make Dynamic Django dependent dropdown

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am new to Django and  I am struggling to make a dynamic Django dependent select dropdown for 'Categories', and I have been making a CRUD with Products having categories ,sub categories ,colors ,size
below is the code for my Products model:

```
from tkinter import CASCADE
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers
# Create your models here.
CATEGORY_CHOICES = [('ninesixwear','9-6WEAR'),('desiswag','DESI SWAG'),('fusionwear','FUSION WEAR'),
                    ('bridalwear','BRIDAL WEAR')]
class Products(models.Model):
    Categories = serializers.ChoiceField(choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    sub_categories = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Colors = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Size = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/',width_field=None,height_field=None,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    sku_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    prod_details = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: This link will help you to create dependent dropdown in django    https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**model file create Category field**

```
class Category (models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
     class Meta:
         verbose_name_plural= 'Categories'
```

**viwe file query all category from database**

```
def category(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
```

**html file code**

```
       <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Category</label>
            <select name="category" class="form-control">
                <option value="">select category</option>
                {% for category in categories %}
                <option value="{{category.id}}">{{category.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
```

*If you still don't understand then check this repo*  [Github](https://github.com/iamfoysal/forum-fullstack)